# Dropzonejs: Attempted to redefine property 'filesizeBase'

Tags: dropzone.js, vue.js

I've integrated DropzoneJs into a VueJs application im putting together. It's running great in both Chrome and Firefox but for some reason the app is very sad in safari. I'm getting the following error in Safari: **Attempted to redefine property 'filesizeBase'.**

**My Vue Component Looks as Follows:**

```
var Dropzone = require('../../vendor/dropzone.min.js');

module.exports = {

template: require('./views/files.html'),

props: ['files', 'is-complete'],

data: function()
{
    return {
        reverse: -1,
        uploading: false,
        token: document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('value'),
        project: document.querySelector('#project').getAttribute('value'),
    }
},

methods: {

    uploadFile: function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var self = this;

        this.uploading = !this.uploading;

        if(this.uploading)
        {
            var myDropzone = new Dropzone("form#mediaUpload", {

                init: function() {

                    this.on("complete", function(file) {
                        setTimeout(function()
                        {
                            self.uploading = false;
                        }, 5000);
                    });

                    this.on("success", function(file, uploadedFile) {
                        self.files.push(uploadedFile);
                    });
                },

                paramName: "file",
                maxFilesize: 250, // MB
                maxFiles: 15,
                uploadMultiple: false,

            });
        }
    },

    deleteFile: function(file, index)
    {

        this.files.pop(index);

        this.$nextTick(function()
        {
            this.$http.post('/upload/'+file.id+'/delete');
        });

    },
},

components: {
    fileSize: require('./FileSize'),
    humanTime: require('../Helpers/HumanTime'),
    mimeType: require('../Helpers/MimeType'),
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: Hey Douglas, thanks for taking the time to look at this. Can you point me in a direction on how to grab that stack trace?